# Move chunks of list to new lines

Tags: python

I have created a script where I generate chunks of 2 elements within a List:

```
chunks = data[x:x+2]
  for x in xrange(0, len(data)2)]
   outfile.write(str(chunks))
```

This generates me a list with chunks containing 2 elements:

```
[[' 0x10', ' 0x00'], [' 0x02', ' 0x11'], [' 0x00', ' 0x04'], [' 0xFF', ' 0x01'], ['  0x00', ' 0x05'], [' 0x22', ' 0x00'], [' 0x10', ' 0x28']]
```

I would like to have the result in a following way:

```
[0x10, 0x00]
[0x02, 0x11]
[0x00, 0x04]
[0xFF, 0x01]
```

Each chunk have to be on a new line. How to move each one chunk on a new line? I tried already with replace.(',', '\n') but it doesn't work or I do not apply correctly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the last line with:

```
for chunk in chunks:
  outfile.write(str(chunk) + '\n')
```

Comment: I just use outfile.write here to reflect what was in the question.